# Query: 2 divs slide right/left

Tags: jquery, slider

I have this html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slide">
        <div id="slide1">
            Content 1
            <a href="#" id="show-slide2">Show Content 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="slide2">
            Content 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#container` has `max-width:1250px`. Onload only `#slide1` should show up. now i want to click on `a#show-slide2` and `#slide2` should slide in from right.

what CSS and JS do I need?

Comment: Does this mean you don't know how to build a CSS? have you tried already something?

Comment: Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RyDuK/).

Comment: I tried a lot, but nothing worked, so I decided to post without my tries ;-) The problem was always the 100% width. Thanx, roXon, for your solution.

Comment: @sugo you're welcome, but please next time try to setup at least a demo, show some more code, will be easier for us to guide you / suggest! Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aqesiw/3/edit)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div id="slides">
  <div>
    Content 1
    <a href="#" id="show-slide2">Show Content 2</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slides{  
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#cf5;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#slides div{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-4px;
  white-space:normal;
  vertical-align:top;
  *display:inline;
  background:#eee;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  var slideW = $('#slides').width();
  $('#show-slide2').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#slides').animate({scrollLeft: slideW }, 600);
  });

});
```